# Cakephp without Save() function?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

May I know , got other way to store the SQL statement, except the Save() function ?
I want to do some simple calculation, i want to store the result at database.
Anyone having any idea about it ?

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        /// complete calculation 

        $data1 = (string) $this->request->data['Calculate']['var1'];
        $data2 = (string) $this->request->data['Calculate']['var2'];

        echo $data1;
        echo '<br/>';
        echo $data2;

        $result = $data1 + $data2;

        echo '<br/>';
        echo $result;

      SQL Statement
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO calculate VALUES('$data1','$data2','$result','2')") or die(mysql_error());
       // if($this->Calculate->save($this->request->data)){

       //     echo'succuful add';


       // }
    }  
 }
```

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples.html

Comment: Dave, i already finish the tutorial.

Comment: you know the virtual fields in page 378 chapter 8 
cakephp cookbook documentation, release 2.x

Comment: cry, because i still new in MVC, now tried myself using the framework. I willing to learn my mistake. sorry sorry sorry.

Comment: It's nice to say that you've finished the tutorials, but when you use literally none of the knowledge you'd gain from the tutorial, it's pretty obvious you haven't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but you're doing it wrong.

The whole point of using Cake is that it contains a Database Abstraction Layer, which takes care of all the messy details of SQL syntax, sql injection attacks, and many other benefits.

If you want to manipulate your data in a special way before saving, you can do something like this:

```
$calculateDetails = array(
    'Calculate' => array(
        'field1' => $data1,
        'field2' => $data2,
        'field3' => $result,
        'field4' => '2'
    )
);

$this->Calculate->save($calculateDetails);
```

Comment: Thank for your help. My program work using this method, your solution are perfectly good .... THANK YOU VERY MUCH ....

Comment: Sir, i will try my best to improve more~

Comment: Oh mr. user, it's OK.  We all had to start somewhere, and often that way is to try to get code that we're used to, to work with cake.  Stick with it and you'll get there :-)